# get Store ID in custom validator - Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, onepage-checkout

I'm creating a custom validator for the checkout process following Magento 2 Documentation for this topic, but now I need to send the Store ID as a parameter of my custom validator, something like:

```
define(
[],
function () {
    'use strict';
    return {
        /**
         * Validate something
         *
         * @returns {boolean}
         */
        validate: function(storeId) {
            if(storeId !== 1) return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following line which will return store id:

```
console.log(window.checkoutConfig.quoteData.store_id)
```

For store code

```
window.checkoutConfig.storeCode
```